# What is the difference between Lookup, Scan and Seek?

Tags: sql-server, terminology

So I found this query

```
SELECT MAX(us.[last_user_lookup]) as [last_user_lookup], MAX(us.[last_user_scan]) 
AS [last_user_scan], MAX(us.[last_user_seek]) as [last_user_seek] 
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats as us 
where us.[database_id] = DB_ID() AND us.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tblName')
group by us.[database_id], us.[object_id];
```

when i look up the documentation on [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql) all it says is

> ```
> last_user_seek      datetime    Time of last user seek
> last_user_scan      datetime    Time of last user scan.
> last_user_lookup    datetime    Time of last user lookup.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Every individual seek, scan, lookup, or update on the specified index by one query execution is counted as a use of that index and increments the corresponding counter in this view. Information is reported both for operations caused by user-submitted queries, and for operations caused by internally generated queries, such as scans for gathering statistics.

Now I understand that when I run the query it's getting the highest time of those 3 fields as `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` can have duplicate `database_id` and `object_id` where one or more of the fields may also be `NULL` (so you can just to a `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY last_user_seek, last_user_scan, last_user_lookup DESC` otherwise you potentially miss data) but when I run it I get values like

```
NULL | 2017-05-15 08:56:29.260 | 2017-05-15 08:54:02.510
```

but I don't understand what the user has done with the table which is represented by these values.

So what is the difference between Lookup, Scan and Seek?

Comment: You'll find some information here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/sql-server/operations perhaps have a read and ask a more specific question

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Basic difference between these operations:

Let's consider that you have two tables. TableA and TableB. Both tables contain more than 1000 000 rows, and both have clustered indexes on Id column. TableB has also nonclustered index on code column. (Remember that your nonclustered index is always pointing at pages of clustered one...)

**seek:**

Let's consider that you want only 1 record from TableA and your clustered index is on column `Id`.
Query should be like:

```
SELECT Name
FROM TableA
WHERE Id = 1
```

Your result contains fewer than 15% (it is something between 10-20, depends on situation) of your full data set... Sql Server performs index seek in this scenario. (optimizer has found a useful index to retrieve data)

**scan:**

For example your query needs more than 15% of data from TableA, then it is necessary to scan the whole index to satisfy the query.
Let's consider that TableB has TableA `Id` column as foreign key from TableA, and TableB contains all `Id`s from TableA. Query should be like:

```
SELECT a.Id
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.Id = b.TableAId
```

Or just

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
```

For index on TableA SQL Server performs use index scan. Because all data (pages) need to satisfy the query...

**lookup:**

Let's consider that TableB has column `dim` and also column `code` and nonclustered index on `code` (as we mentioned).
SQL Server will use lookup when it needs to retrieve non key data from the data page and nonclustered index is used to resolve the query.
For example key lookup could be used in query like:

```
SELECT id, dim
FROM TableB
WHERE code = 'codeX'
```

- You can resolve it by covering index (include `dim` to nonclustered one)